# json-rpc api works locally but getting "Connection Refused" remotely

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc

code:

```
from bitcoinrpc.authproxy import AuthServiceProxy
class ProxyService:
    def getProxy(self) -> AuthServiceProxy:
        return AuthServiceProxy("http://%s:%s@xx.xx.xx.xx:8332" % ("xx", "xxx")) # this only works locally as 127.0.0.1
```

bitcon.config

```
datadir=/xxxx/Bitcoin
dbcache=2000
txindex=1
server=1
rpcuser=xx
rpcpassword=xx
rpcport=8332
disablewallet=1
```

I am running this on Ubuntu droplet. connection works when i connect locally as 127.0.0.1:8332

but when i try connection to the ip of my node **(locally or remotely)** I get "connection refused"

also i can confirm my node is up

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to set

```
rpcallowip=<ip>
```

for each of your remote IPs, to whitelist them.

You can also use a netmask instead of IP. If you have a dynamic IP, use this feature!

For example, if your laptop's IP always starts with `237.94`, you can set it to

```
rpcallowip=237.94.0.0/255.255.0.0
```

Then it'll allow all IPs that start with those numbers. Make sure to set a really strong password, though.